# Nodejs Passport - Using Multiple Google Strategies

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I am not sure if this is possible but I would like to use multiple Google strategies in order to use a different set of scopes depending on the link/user.

I have created two separate passport variables:

```
 passport = require('passport')
 passport2 = require('passport')
```

I have setup them both as follows:

```
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/callback"
},
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    // asynchronous verification, for effect...                                                                    
    process.nextTick(function (){

      // Changing this to return the accessToken instead of the profile information                                
        console.log(profile.displayName);                                                                        

      return done(null, [{token:accessToken,rToken:refreshToken,'profile':profile}]);
    });
  }
));


passport2.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/join/callback"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    // asynchronous verification, for effect...                                                                    
    process.nextTick(function (){

      // Changing this to return the accessToken instead of the profile information                                
        //console.log(profile);                                                                        

      return done(null, [{token:accessToken,rToken:refreshToken,'profile':profile}]);
    });
  }
))
```

For my routes I have this:

```
app.get('/auth',
passport.authenticate('google', {scope: ['scopes'],
                                 accessType:'offline', approvalPrompt:'force'})
);

app.get('/joinreq',
    passport2.authenticate('google', {scope: ['different_scopes]})
);
```

And my callbacks look like this:

```
app.get('/join/callback', function(req,res){
    console.log('made it to the join callback');
    res.redirect('/great')

}

app.get('/auth/callback', function(req,res){
    console.log('made it to the auth callback');
    res.redirect('/index')
}
```

I am able to successfully authenticate with each scope successfully - the problem I'm running into is that my callback is only going to the `/join/callback`.
It seems like the variable `passport2` is overwriting the value of `passport`.

Is there any way I can get around this?  I want a set of scopes for admin users and a set of scopes for everyone else.

Comment: As a side note. `require` is called only once. The subsequent calls return a cache version of the initial require call.

Answer (score 12):

A slightly cleaner way is to set up separate auth points with separate names, rather than overwriting the registered strategy on each request.  By default, passport gives GoogleStrategy the name `"google"`, but you can specify a different name as the first argument to install a second strategy.

```
// set up first Google strategy
passport.use('google', new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/join/callback"
  }, function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    ...
  }
)

// Second strategy -- could use different callback URL, etc.
passport.use('google-alt', new GoogleStrategy({
    ...
});

app.get('/auth', passport.authenticate('google', ['scopes']))
app.get('/joinauth', passport.authenticate('google-alt', ['scopes']))
```

Comment: this is what I was looking for a long time. Thank you:)

Answer (score 1):

This was solved by creating two middleware functions to define the passport variable depending on the route:

```
app.get('/auth',middlefunc,passport.authenticate('google',['scopes']))
app.get('/joinauth',middlefunc2,passport.authenticate('google',['scopes']))


function middlefunc(req,res,next){
    passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/join/callback"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    // asynchronous verification, for effect...                                                                    
    process.nextTick(function (){

      // Changing this to return the accessToken instead of the profile information                                
        //console.log(profile);                                                                        

      return done(null, [{token:accessToken,rToken:refreshToken,'profile':profile}]);
    });
  }
))
    }

function middlefunc2(req,res,next){
    //another definition of passport.use

}
```

There was no need to make another `passport` variable.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
router.get('/', passport.authenticate('google', {
    scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'],
}));
```