# Express OAuth Authorization for Different Access Methods

Tags: express, authentication, oauth-2.0, routes, passport.js

I am looking to figure out best practices for the following scenario.  I am a relatively new/hobby programmer.  I am developing a chat bot that is using Dialogflow. I want users to be able to use different messaging apps to be able to access the data and information in a backed database, but that I want the users to be authenticated (I need to know who they are in order to query relevant data).  I also have a website where users can create an account and login.

I have created the website and all of the OAuth connection is working fine.  I am storing the information on account creation to keep track of users.

Where I am stuck, is that I want to be able to authenticate users on the messaging platforms to link to their accounts on my database (token/some sort of simple profile identifier).

I am looking for advice on the OAuth flow and routing.  I am using Express.  Let's use Google Account Linking as an example:

**One way to create/access account:**

Website -> SignUp/Login -> Send Out to Google -> Confirm Identity -> Return to Callback (within protected area of website).

**Another way to access account:**

DialogFlow Chat -> Send to webhook (I want to have this route protected) -> Authenticate/Recognize User -> Query Data -> Return Information to user's device.  This process requires access to the same flow as the website process.  As I have it now, my callback always refers back to the internal page within my website.  But I would imagine I do not want that if a user is trying to access information via Google Assistant.

**Is it best/better practices to:**

- Handle the different flows via route conditional statements?
- Set up different route endpoints using the same account logic (I am using passport.js) but specify different callback urls?
- Register different API credentials with different urls to handle the different methods of access?
- How do you handle callbacks coming from within a messaging app?

In my newbie self, am I over complicating this an is there a simpler and more elegant solution?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving the problem myself.

I looked at this SO answer here ([Nodejs Passport - Using Multiple Google Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26786756/nodejs-passport-using-multiple-google-strategies)).

For those that need/want code.

My routes are:

```
// GOOGLE ROUTER

  //process route to verification
    router.get('/google', passport.authenticate('google', { scope : ['profile', 'email'] }));

  //callback after verification
    router.get('/google/callback', passport.authenticate('google', {
        successRedirect : '/profile',
        failureRedirect : '/'
    }));

// DIALOGFLOW ROUTER
   router.get('/auth', passport.authenticate('google-dialogflow', { scope : [ 'email'] }));
```

I added the separate name parameter in the authenticate method.

Then in a passport.js file I have two passport strategies.  One starts with:

```
passport.use('google',new GoogleStrategy({
   clientID        : configAuth.googleAuth.clientID,
   clientSecret    : configAuth.googleAuth.clientSecret,
   callbackURL     : configAuth.googleAuth.callbackURL,
   passReqToCallback : true
},
function(req, token, refreshToken, profile, done) {...
```

and the other starts with:

```
passport.use('google-dialogflow',new GoogleStrategy({
   clientID        : configAuth.dialogAuth.clientID,
   clientSecret    : configAuth.dialogAuth.clientSecret,
   callbackURL     : configAuth.dialogAuth.callbackURL,
   passReqToCallback : true 
},
function(req, token, refreshToken, profile, done) {...
```

I also created a different credential in the Google API console, so that I could use different credentials (clientID, clientSecret, callbackURl) for the different means of accessing the data/site.

Again, I don't know if this is best or even good practice but it solved my problem.